# Can y' be squared? $\frac{dy}{dx} ye^{xy}=3x$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So the question I am trying to solve is: find
$\frac{dy}{dx}$ if  $ye^{xy}=3x$

I have tried:

$\frac{d}{dx} ye^{xy}=\frac{d}{dx}3x$, factor out constant, and add y':

 $yy'\frac{d}{dx} e^{xy}=3$, derivative of $e^u$ is $e^u$, use chain rule on u=(xy)

 
$yy' e^{xy}\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=3$, Using the product rule I should be left with:

 
$yy' e^{xy}(xy'+(1)y)=3$, expand and factor:

 
$y^2(y')^2x$ $ e^{xy}=3$

$(y')^2$$=\frac{3}{ xe^{xy}y^2}$

$dy/dx$$=\sqrt\frac{3}{ xe^{xy}y^2}$

But that doesn't seem right.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you are differentiating each side of the equation $ye^{xy}=3x$? That is not what you wrote! If so, use the product rule on the left-hand side.

Comment: What is the question? It seems like you're confusing $dy/dx$ and $d/dx$. Your first line is the same as $y'ye^{xy}=3x$

Comment: the actual question i am to solve is, Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$if $ye^{xy}=3x$ Sorry this is my first calculus course, and I am new to posting here. I will try to edit question. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ ye^{xy}=3x$$
Take the derivative of both sides. Note the chain rule and product rule used.
$$y'e^{xy} + ye^{xy}*(y+xy')= 3$$
Factor out $e^{xy}$
$$e^{xy} (y'+y(y+xy')) = 3$$
$$e^{xy} (y'+y^2+xyy') = 3$$
$$y'+y^2+xyy'=\frac{3}{e^{xy}}$$Factor out $y'$
$$y'(1+xy)+y^2 = \frac{3}{e^{xy}}$$
$$y'(1+xy) = \frac{3}{e^{xy}} - y^2$$
$$y' = \frac{3}{e^{xy}(1+xy)} - \frac{y^2}{1+xy}$$

Comment: Great, thank you, I see I should have used product rule immediately: $y'e^{xy} + ye^{xy}$ and then I wouldn't be multiplying $y'\cdot y'$ Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you had to take another derivative (the second derivative) then you could get $(y')^2$ terms.